# .h file not found when build tensorflow android demo with bazel

Tags: android, tensorflow, bazel

error occurred(.h file not found,and different .h file every time I build) when I build tf android demo with bazel.I've tried some ways proposed in this website,but not solved my problem.please help me,very thanks!

[image]
And sometimes another .h file not found
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOq7F.png)

Comment: What is the command line that you used to build?

Comment: `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo

`

Comment: I changed `ndk` version to r12,but id didn't build successfully either.

Comment: yeah,it build successfully just now! I forget to edit `NDK` path to new version in file `WORKSPACE`,thank you very much!